# Finding complex conjugate roots of the auxiliary equation!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $\sin x$ is a solution to the following differential equation!
$$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}+2\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+6\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+5y=0$$

By inspection I have already found out another zeroes of the equation that is $\cos x$ because $e^{bix}=c_1\cos x+ c_2\sin x$ hence $b=1$

I have no idea for the other pair. It seems to me that carry our long polynomial division does not make sense here! I hope that someone will provide a better way of doing this. I haven't tried the reduction order method. If I carry out I think it would be a mess to handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of the ODE is
$$P(z):=z^4+2z^3+6z^2+2z+5$$
If $\sin(x)$ is a solution then $(z+i)(z-i)=z^2+1$ divides $P$. Can you find the full factorization of $P$?

Comment: Thanks I got it now!